# Why does the file "shell.php.jpg" can execute as a php file but "shell.jpg" cannot?

Tags: vulnerability, file-upload, burp-suite, web, dvwa

I am learning about file upload vulnerabilities using [DVWA](http://www.dvwa.co.uk/).

After cranking the website's security level to High,
the website checks both the post request's content type & file extension, so in order to bypass it I changed the file extension to `.jpg` and used Burp Proxy to change the file name to `shell.php.jpg` from `shell.jpg` in order to execute the shell.

[image: changing filename with burp]

It works.
What I don't understand is why it works. I read that only the right most file extension pattern is treated as the file extension, So that must mean `shell.php.jpg` should be treated as a `.jpg` file, and It is treated as such - the upload succeeds.

But why can I execute this file and not a `shell.jpg` file if the file extension stayed the same and the `.php` part is just part of the file name?

```
root@kali:~# weevely http://10.0.2.4/dvwa/hackable/uploads/shell2.php.jpg yuval

[+] weevely 3.7.0

[+] Target: www-data@10.0.2.4:/var/www/dvwa/hackable/uploads
[+] Session:    /root/.weevely/sessions/10.0.2.4/shell2.php_0.session
[+] Shell:  System shell

[+] Browse the filesystem or execute commands starts the connection
[+] to the target. Type :help for more information.

weevely> id
[-][channel] The remote script execution triggers an error 500, check script and payload integrity
uid=33(www-data) gid=33(www-data) groups=33(www-data)
www-data@10.0.2.4:/var/www/dvwa/hackable/uploads $
```

Example of the file working as expected named as `shell.php.jpg`.

```
root@kali:~# weevely http://10.0.2.4/dvwa/hackable/uploads/shell.jpg yuval

[+] weevely 3.7.0

[+] Target: 10.0.2.4
[+] Session:    /root/.weevely/sessions/10.0.2.4/shell_1.session

[+] Browse the filesystem or execute commands starts the connection
[+] to the target. Type :help for more information.

weevely> id
[!][terminal] Backdoor communication failed, check URL availability and password
```

Example of the same file NOT working as expected named as `shell.jpg`.

Comment: It shouldnt work.How is it working for you

Comment: The help section states to use another vulnerability along with it to get the shell

Comment: @VipulNair Mind linking me to this help section?

Comment: cd /var/www/html/DVWA-master/vulnerabilities/upload/help/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> shell.php.jpg **should be** treated as a .jpg file

You're exploring DVWA, so not every **should be** means **is**. If I had to guess, the upload script properly checks the extension of the file and allows it, but the webserver doesn't check it the same way and allows execution.

You can learn more by exploring web server's (nginx or apache) config files, look for a block that performs handover to php parser for request processing.

Clarification:

> But why can I execute this file and not a `shell.jpg` file if the file extension stayed the same and the `.php` part is just part of the file name?

The extension is just letters in a file name, they do not determine how the file is handled by the web server, web server determines it. One of the common algorithms is:

```
If the requested file name ends with “php”
    Invoke php to handle the request
Else
    Serve the requested file like any other static file
End
```

I’m guessing that in your case `requested file name ends with “php”` is changed to `requested file name contains “.php”`. You can find this rule in the configuration file of the web server that’s processing your requests and find out for yourself.

Update:

This is the expected and documented behaviour of apache. I'm a little bit surprised, but this is the world we live in. Goddamnit.

In configuration file `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php.conf` line `AddHandler php5-cgi .php` registers handler for `.php` files. Everything is OK, unless you read [what AddHandler does](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_mime.html#addhandler).

> The extension argument is case-insensitive and can be specified with or without a leading dot. **Filenames may have multiple extensions and the extension argument will be compared against each of them.**

Sooo... Yeah. Of course filenames may have multiple extensions. This is the only logical default.

If you're a weirdo expecting that the file would have only one extension, apache [has the answer for you](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_mime.html#multipleext):

> If you would prefer only the last dot-separated part of the filename to be mapped to a particular piece of meta-data, then **do not use the Add* directives.**

They helpfully suggest the solution to your weird wish of one-extention-ness – just use regex. So in order to execute only .php files as php you need to replace AddHandler directive in php.conf with

```
<FilesMatch "[^.]+\.php$">
  SetHandler php5-cgi
</FilesMatch>
```

In conclusion:

- common sense doesn't exist in software
- never trust any data provided by user
- store original filenames in the database if needed and rename them after upload
- treat filenames like a live bomb

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance but I still can't understand how this answers my question, mind elaborating?

Comment: @Yuval tried to clarify it a bit. In the end your question is about web server’s behavior, and the answer is in the config files of the server.

Comment: Not knowing anything about DVWA I expect this to be the correct answer.  Now I think about it, I've seen this vulnerability in my nodejs express configuration.  However, concerning DVWA, it seems to be a straw-man when it comes to vulnerability.  Does DVWA have documentation on why this works?

Comment: Thanks for clearing it! I didn't even think that the server would handle the requested file in such a way, sounds a bit basic to check if it ends with and not if it contains... I want to hope its part of what makes DVWA so damn vulnerable? lol

@NathanGoings I could not find any documentation for DVWA, do you recommend a better - more documented vulnerable website? (:

Comment: @Yuval, My website circa 2004 was way more vulnerable.  I'm not really suggesting  an alternative to DVWA, you did learn about contains-vs-ends-with, so I think it's solving it's purpose.  Here's the documentation I found: https://github.com/ethicalhack3r/DVWA/blob/master/docs/DVWA_v1.3.pdf

Comment: @Yuval I took a look at the DVWA and they do not include apache/nginx configuration as a part of the app, so just look at the web server config files on your DVWA and find out if my theory is correct. As for documentation, it's unnecessary and often detrimental. If you're trying to learn hacking, you should look at the code/configuration/assembly instructions (how the software runs), not at the documentation (how the programmer thinks software runs). You can't just learn a bunch of vulnerabilities, you have to search and find them yourself.

Comment: @NathanGoings Thanks! I found something pretty interesting in the docs, "High – This level is to give an example to the user of good coding practises.
This level should be secure against all vulnerabilities." So high shouldn't have been vulnerable at all.

I'll go look at the web server config files and report back (-:

Comment: Okay so after I gave it a look, I found that my metasploitable 2 vm which runs the dvwa app is using apache2 and I acquired this apache2.conf file https://pastebin.com/raw/xBNgTFbJ but I can't find the request processing block you were writing about, would you be able to enlighten me some more by looking at the file? (:

Comment: @Yuval The site config is in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/`, this is the general apache configuration file. You can see at the bottom the line that includes them: `Include /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/`

Comment: Oh, sorry - I found a file named "000-default" in the "sites-enabled" folder containing this https://pastebin.com/raw/T83HN8dn

Comment: @Yuval I solved it, see update. I can't say that I'm happy about it, I was overly optimistic in estimating our capability to handle filenames.

Comment: That something like Apache handles extensions in this way is almost beyond belief... my flabber is absolutely gasted!

Comment: @TripeHound Welcome to IT security, get used to it :-/ I once found that you can erase the whole server by deleting a user with username `../../..` in one application...